# How to use KLogger?

Tags: php, frameworks

**Common handler i used**

```
<?php
function error_msg($err_type,$err_msg,$err_file,$err_line)
{
$fh=fopen("error/errorlog.txt","a");
$date1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$er="
===============================================================================================================
"."
Error: Type: ".$err_type."Message: ".$err_msg."ErrorFile: ".$err_file."Errorline: ".$err_line."Time: ".$date1.
"
===============================================================================================================
";
fwrite($fh,$er);
fclose($fh);
}
set_error_handler("error_msg");
?>
```

These codes Log error perfectly. Since i am using framework i cant use this codes. so i am using KLogger. KLogger perfectly logs my error but it also display error in front screen to user.

**How to log error using KLogger If any one use this KLogger Help me how to use with simple examples.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
require_once 'KLogger.php';

$log = KLogger::instance('/var/log/');
$log->logInfo('Returned a million search results');
$log->logFatal('Oh dear.');

# Output will log to the path you specified, at log_[current-date].txt
```

It's crazy simple. [Read the docs at GitHub](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger)

PS, I wrote KLogger.

Comment: I can log error but infront screen error is displayed. for eg(If mailid misspelled while sending in php) I can log error using KLogger. but i should not want to display error in front screen.

Comment: @Kenny I'm trying to use Klogger exactly as described. I don't get errors, but I also don't see the log file.  Is there more configuration that needs to be done? Directory permissions, etc?